# Can the output of the MICE pool() function by grouped using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, imputation, r-mice

After the multiple imputation of some data set using the MICE package, I would like to calculate separate linear regression models for each of the two dependent variables (score_1, score_2). The independent variables (arm, sex, age, baseline score) are identical for both models. Unfortunately, I don't manage (1) to integrate the mice::pool() function into a dplyr pipeline, and (2) I don't know how to group the mice::pool() function by the dependent variable (df_lm$score).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)


# SIMULATE DATA


df <- data.frame(id = 1:120,
                 arm = sample(c('intervention', 'control'), 120, replace = TRUE),
                 sex = sample(c('m', 'f'), 120, replace = TRUE),
                 age = round(rnorm(120, 55, 10)),
                 score_1 = round(rnorm(120, 50, 5)),
                 score_2 = round(rnorm(120, 50, 7)))

df <- df %>% bind_rows(df) %>%
  mutate(time = c(rep('baseline', 120), rep('follow_up', 120))) %>%
  select(id, arm, time, everything()) %>%
  gather(score, measure , -(id:age)) %>%
    spread(key = time, value = measure)

# INSERT SOME MISSING VALUES

df$follow_up[seq(1, 240, 5)] <- NA

# IMPUTATION MODEL 

init <- mice(df, maxit = 0)
predM <- init$predictorMatrix
# remove as predictor
predM[ , c('arm')] <- 0


mids_from_df <- mice(df,
  method = 'pmm',
  predictorMatrix = predM,
  m = 5,
  seed = 123,
  print = FALSE
)


# COMPUTE MODELS


fmla <- "follow_up ~ baseline + arm + sex + age"

df_lm <- mids_from_df %>%
  mice::complete("long", include = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(.imp, score) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(lm_model = map(data, ~lm(fmla, data = .)))
```

I would like to get the pooled results for each dependent variable separately. However, I don't know how to use mice::pool() along with dplyr and purr. The following code throws an error:

```
df_lm <- mids_from_df %>%
  mice::complete("long", include = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(.imp, score) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(lm_model = map(data, ~lm(fmla, data = .)))  %>%
  group_by(.imp, score) %>%
  pool(., lm_model) # does not work
```

The error message is: "Error: No glance method for objects of class integer"

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When you use `group_by(.imp, score)`, you have one row per group, so one model per group, right? So what are you pooling over?

Comment: This seems to work: `mids_from_df %>%
    mice::complete("long", include = FALSE) %>%
    group_by(.imp, score) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(lm_model = map(data, ~lm(fmla, data = .)))  %>%
    group_split(score) %>% 
    map(~pool(.$lm_model))`

Comment: I'm guessing there's some odd things going on with nse in the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- it really seems to work!